# Letter case permutation

Tags: python, permutation

I am trying to get all of the letter case permutations for a string and add them into one list like this:

```
allperm('an') should produce:
['an', 'aN', 'An', 'AN']
```

but my Output is multiple lists:

```
['a', 'n']
['a', 'N']
```

This is my current code

```
def allperm(password):
   n = len(password)

   #2^n permuations
   max = 1 << n

   #lowercase password (base)
   password = password.lower()

   #get all permutations
   for i in range(max):
       perm  = [k for k in password]
       for j in range(n):
           if (((i >> j) & 1) == 1):
               perm[j] = password[j].upper()

       #add to list
     temp = ""
      for i in perm:
           temp += i
      return(temp)
```

Comment: im so confused, where did all the numbers and operations like `i >> j` come from?! This should be a much simpler task dealing directly with strings. Also, im really scared if this is an implementation of some kind of "password".

Comment: Do you want to use *your* code or do you just want to solve this problem? Because `itertools` seems like it would make this a lot easier.

Comment: `an` -> `['an', 'aN', 'An', 'AN']` is not really a permutation

Comment: What would `allperm('abc')` produce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `zip` the lowercase characters of the password with the uppercase ones, and pass them to `itertools.product` to generate the desired permutations:

```
from itertools import product
def allperm(password):
    return list(map(''.join, product(*zip(password.lower(), password.upper()))))
```

so that `allperm('an')` returns:

```
['an', 'aN', 'An', 'AN']
```